# Dynamic column lengths with ng-repeat and bootstrap

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

With something like the following:

```
<div class="row" ng-repeat="(k, v) in idata">
    <div class="col-lg-6">
        <h2>Network Bytes: {{k}}</h2>
        <div class="chart" ts-rickshaw="v"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Is there a way I could insert a row every X items (2 in this case since it is col-lg-6)? I'm aware I could probably change my data to be an array and do some logic in the controller. But ideally there should be a way to do this that keeps the view logic out of the controller.

Comment: You could use `ng-switch` like this: http://www.bootply.com/86855

Comment: @Skelly: Yup I have seen that solution. It seems okay, but still requires I change my controller logic since I am working with a hash and not an array

Comment: @Skelly: But it works, so I guess I will go with it :-P

Comment: Otherwise you can create a directive (let's call it jumpingTable) and pass to the element the number of keys in the object (`Object.keys(obj).length`) [only for EC5 compliant] and then make all the calculations you need inside the directive itself.

Answer (score 1):

I went with the ng-switch strategy suggested by @Skelly. However I modified it to make it more generic so I could avoid the code repetition for each column by adding a nested loop and referencing `$parent.$index`:

```
<div ng-repeat="i in fsdata track by $index" ng-init="rows = [1,2]">
    <span ng-switch="" on="$index % rows.length">
        <div class="row" ng-switch-when="0">
            <div class="col-lg-{{12/rows.length}}" ng-show="fsdata[$parent.$index+$index]" ng-repeat="i in rows">
                <h2>Disk: {{fsdata[$parent.$index+$index].name}} <small>({{fs_current[$parent.$index+$index].c_val | bytes}} / {{fs_current[$parent.$index+$index].total | bytes}}) {{fs_current[$parent.$index+$index].percent_used|number:0}}% Used</small></h2>
                <div class="chart" max="{{fs_total[fsdata[$parent.$index+$index].name]}}" ts-rickshaw="fsdata[$parent.$index+$index].data"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

What about using $index and the modulus operator?

```
<div class="row" ng-repeat="(k, v) in idata">
    <div class="col-lg-6">
        <h2>Network Bytes: {{k}}</h2>
        <div class="chart" ts-rickshaw="v"></div>
    </div>
    <div ng-if="($index != 0) && ($index % 2)">My Even Row</div>
</div>
```

Comment: The issue that every x columns should be *enclosed* in the the div. Seems like angular doesn't like to do this with any sort of view markup. So for this strategy to work I would need to be able to do ng-if on both the opening and close tags of the div.